# even though using _ denotes private, can I set it as a property?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have 2 variables.  `model` and `_model`.   Essentially, model is going to be the property that people would bind to with my template.  When it binds, it will set `_model` and then `_model` will be used in the dart and in the markup for the form binding.

My question is this.  I know in Dart, the underscore is a denotation of a private variable.  i wasnt sure if it being *private* encompasses the scope of the markup associated with the Dart class.

That being said.  It seems that when I set:

```
_model = new Model();
```

the class understands it just fine, but if I want to notify the markup using *set* by way of:

```
set("_model", new Model());
```

the class doesnt understand it.  It is almost as if there are 2 different scopes of `_model`.  Maybe I can get by this by changing all references of `_model` to something like `componentModel` or something else which doesnt use an underscore at all.

Can someone explain this more clearly to me, because I think I am missing something when it comes to pre-pending an underscore and plausibly how *set* works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect from

```
_model = new Model();
```

This is normal code and expected to work.

```
set("_model", new Model());
```

needs to use reflection to set the value of the `_model` property and I'm pretty sure this can't work because there is no way to access private fields from another library. There could be a way for a transformer to change the code (for example add public getters and setters) that would allow code to access private members. But as far as I remember, this is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i thought.  I was hoping to have a private property which could be reflected to my markup, while staying private to the class and not be overridden by parent components etc

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. There are efforts to introduce annotations to get analyzer support even when it's not enforced at runtime. The analyzer supports `@protected` and perhaps they add `@final` or something like that. Check out https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta (not all of these annotations are already supported by the analyzer)

Comment: Colleagues didnt like i was leveraging their reflected properties after reading their code, and I was trying to find a way to set them up for more private and protected status items, inhibiting the use by other devs. :-/

Comment: You could try `@visibleForTesting`. That should not be used except from code in `test/`. Not sure if the analyzer already supports it.